# Getting file structure in the client browser even when offline using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, file-structure

I want to display the file structure of the my project folder (downloaded from my site only) in the user/client's web browser even when user is offline.

Example:

my_project/
│      css/
│        │  style.css
│
│      js/
│        │  js.js
│
└ index.html

when user opens index.html on web browser the above file structure must be generated automatically.

My biggest problem is, i don't know how to achieve cross browser compatibility.

Note: I have already tried http://jslib.mozdev.org/ but i got nothing.